# Steps needed to configure HBase in a HA mode in apache hadoop2?

Tags: hbase, hadoop2, high-availability

I am using hadoop 2.6.0 and hbase 0.98.7, I have configured HA for hdfs / namenode . I have active nn1 and standby nn2 being displayed. Now the issue is i am unable to enable High Availability for hbase , also i dont understand how to integrate hbase with HA enabled hdfs. Also while doing jps HMaster is running but unable to see the UI for hbase.

My core site.xml

```
<configuration>
<property>
<name>fs.defaultFS</name>
<value>hdfs://ha-cluster</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>dfs.journalnode.edits.dir</name>
<value>/opt/hadoop/HA/data/jn</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

My hdfs site.xml

```
<configuration>
 <property>
 <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
 <value>/opt/hadoop/HA/data/namenode</value>
 </property>
 <property>
 <name>dfs.replication</name>
 <value>1</value>
 </property>
 <property>
 <name>dfs.permissions</name>
 <value>false</value>
 </property>
 <property>
 <name>dfs.nameservices</name>
 <value>ha-cluster</value>
 </property>
 <property>
 <name>dfs.ha.namenodes.ha-cluster</name>
 <value>nn1,nn2</value>
 </property>
 <property>
 <name>dfs.namenode.rpc-address.ha-cluster.nn1</name>
 <value>nn1.cluster.com:9000</value>
 </property>
 <property>
 <name>dfs.namenode.rpc-address.ha-cluster.nn2</name>
 <value>nn2.cluster.com:9000</value>
 </property>
 <property>
 <name>dfs.namenode.http-address.ha-cluster.nn1</name>
 <value>nn1.cluster.com:50070</value>
 </property>
 <property>
 <name>dfs.namenode.http-address.ha-cluster.nn2</name>
 <value>nn2.cluster.com:50070</value>
 </property>
 <property>
 <name>dfs.namenode.shared.edits.dir</name>
 <value>qjournal://nn1.cluster.com:8485;nn2.cluster.com:8485;dn1.cluster.com:8485/ha-cluster</value>
 </property>
 <property>
 <name>dfs.client.failover.proxy.provider.ha-cluster</name>
 <value>org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.ha.ConfiguredFailoverProxyProvider</value>
 </property>
 <property>
 <name>dfs.ha.automatic-failover.enabled</name>
 <value>true</value>
 </property>
 <property>
 <name>ha.zookeeper.quorum</name>
 <value>nn1.cluster.com:2181,nn2.cluster.com:2181,dn1.cluster.com:2181</value>
 </property>
 <property>
 <name>dfs.ha.fencing.methods</name>
 <value>shell(/bin/true)</value>
 </property>
 <property>
 <name>dfs.ha.fencing.ssh.private-key-files</name>
 <value>/home/hadoop/.ssh/id_rsa</value>
 </property>
</configuration>
```

My hbase site.xml

```
<configuration>
<property>
<name>hbase.master</name>
<value>test-hmaster-1-aws.icare.com:60000</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>hbase.rootdir</name>
<value>hdfs://ha-cluster/hbase</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>hbase.cluster.distributed</name>
<value>true</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort</name>
<value>2181</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>
<value>test-hmaster-1-aws.icare.com,test-hslave-1-aws.icare.com,test-kerberos-aws.icare.com</value>
</property> 
</configuration>
```

Comment: First, dfs.journalnode.edits.dir config must be applied in the hdfs-site.xml file not in the core-site.xml. In order to see what is wrong, please provide HMaster logs.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, after you configure HDFS HA, your `fs.defaultFS` becomes `hdfs://ha-cluster`. You are also using it as part of `hbase.rootdir` in your `hbase-site.xml`. Thus you **ARE** integrating with HA enabled HDFS. There is nothing more to do.

Secondly, HBase HA is different from HDFS HA. Basically, you need to configure multiple HBase master instances. One of them is the active master and rest of master instances become the backup masters.

To tell you the truth, I am a little spoiled by Cloudera Manager, in which all you need to do to enable HBase HA is to add multiple HBase instances. However, if you do not use any vendor distribution of HBase and have to configure it manually, you can follow the instruction here
http://hbase.apache.org/book.html#quickstart_fully_distributed

Thirdly, I don't know why the master UI cannot be accessed. But since your instance is in AWS, maybe you need to configure the security group setting to open the port access?